# cross-fade gallery of images with 3 images left to it

Tags: css, css-animations, fadein, fadeout, cross-fade

I have a fiddle as shown below in which at the **position 4 (picture 4, picture 5, picture 6)**, I want **cross-fade(fade-in/fade-out)** gallery of images to happen. At present, it is showing only **picture 6** at that position.

https://jsfiddle.net/k0vzthne/embedded/result

This is the CSS codes which I have used in the fiddle. At this moment, I don't see any cross-fade (fade-in/fade-out) gallery of images going on at position 4.

```
.featured-block a:nth-of-type(4), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(5), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 568px;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  opacity: 1;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}


.featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
  0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;z-index: 999;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;z-index: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the **CSS codes above** so that **cross-fade gallery of images** happen at **position 4** (containing picture 4, picture 5 and picture 6) having
**3 images left** to it as present in the fiddle right now at **position 1, position 2 and position 3**.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is helping if i understand right:

```css
.item
{
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}

.item:nth-child(2n)
{
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 400ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.item:hover + .item
{
  background: green;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">1 </div>
  <div class="item">2 </div>
  <div class="item">3 </div>
  <div class="item">4 </div>
  <div class="item">5 </div>
  <div class="item">6 </div>
</div>
```

---